# git push is taking forever on large codebase despite very small commit -- why, and is that fixable?

Tags: git, bitbucket, large-files, git-push, git-clone

(Sorry if this is answered before -- I couldn't find this specific problem, everyone else is having it for unrelated reasons. Feel free to just point me to the one I missed.)

I'm working with a repo that is very large because of commits of numerous large files. I recently shallow cloned it (depth=1), then later pulled a large change on master. Then I branched, made a small commit, and pushed to that new branch. It's taking forever to push it up, even though it's only adding a small commit (15 kb, one file affected) on top of commit that the remote (Bitbucket) already knows about. The message I see looks like this:

```
silasbarta$ git push origin HEAD
Counting objects: 21034, done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (11817/11817), done.
Writing objects:   4% (967/21034), 406.50 MiB | 1.36 MiB/s
```

Running `git gc` didn't change this.

Why would it need to deal with all those objects? It should just need to know my commit diff and the reference to the previous commit hash, which is already on the origin, right?

Comment: Your commit graph is probably not what you think it is.  Visualize it with `git log --graph --oneline --decorate --all`  (or use GitKraken, GitGui or whatever visualizes the commit graph)

Comment: I don't know if it's too late now to run that, but with that command I just see my branch commits (made a second since) plus the two on master I was aware of (original clone plus one pulled in). So it looks exactly as I thought it would be.

Comment: Also, on any subsequent commits/pushes I don't have this problem. (But may still be an issue if I squash and force-push.)

Comment: OK but is there a line between those 2 commits?  Don't just look at the commits but how they're related on the graph

Comment: Yes, it was just four lines of commits, nothing between any of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are some cases when using a shallow clone where the sending Git doesn't realize that the receiving Git has most of the files already.  This is because the way one Git understands what another Git has is by hash IDs.  Shallow clones mess with hash IDs: commit `a123456` says it has `b789abc` as a parent, and then there's a special record that says *... but we don't have `b789abc`*.  Git then pretends that `a123456` isn't `a123456` after all.

Some cases could be handled better, but aren't.  Using a slightly deeper clone (`--depth 2`) *might* have avoided this, but nothing is really guaranteed here.  Git's code trades a bit of imperfection in determining what it can omit, in order to make the usual cases faster.

Comment: Ah, okay interesting! Still, weird that it can't recognize that I'm just appending one commit.

Comment: yeah... 1 is pretty shallow ;)

Comment: Incidentally, there was a bug introduced in the v2 protocol in Git 2.26, and if you're seeing unusually large amounts of data with `git push` you can also try forcing v0 protocol with `git -c protocol.version=0 push`. (This should not happen with other Git versions unless you explicitly choose protocol v2, as v0 was the default until 2.26.)